# Javascript onclick and ondblclick in same button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

does anybody know an solution for buttons to react on 2 click events for only one button:

```
<input type="button" value="Click" ondblclick="alert('double')"; onclick="alert('ones')";>
```

@At my try if I double click on button, it alert only 'ones';
Why it isn't possible to have ondblclick and onclick in the same button?

Comment: Is it something like you want to restrict the user from double-clicking?

Comment: Then don't use alert which is modal and fired a blur event in most browsers

Comment: why do you want such behavior doesnt look good to me

Comment: If you double click the button then alert('ones') will appear on your screen.What do you wants to do ?

Comment: It is possible, but why would you want a double-click handler on a button element? It could make sense on a number of other elements (e.g., an option element within a (non drop-down) select element where one click selects and the second submits or something), but I've never needed to handle a double-click on a button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="Click" ondblclick="console.log('double');" onclick="console.log('ones')";>
```

Magically, it works!

Your problem is you are using `alert()` which is modal and so makes your ondblclick event impossible to be fired.

Comment: +1, I think the explanation as to why the double click was not firing was what was needed.

Comment: As answered by upvote, it actually lets you doubleclick but that also fires click event twice. :)

Comment: @GaneshPandhere That's a given, seeing as double = 2

Comment: @GaneshPandhere you can still throttle click event. But i still don't know what exactly OP is looking for... Maybe expected result or not, who knows?!

Comment: even i am not sure about what is the final result expected. :)

Answer (score 2):

You an give timeout for click so that alert pops up bit slow..

```
<input type="button" value="Click" ondblclick="alert('double')"; onclick="setTimeout(function(){alert('ones')},3000);";>
```

Comment: Don't use an interval at least

Comment: @GaneshPandhere now it wont

Comment: Reduce the time limit for setTimeout plss, its too much :-) hehehe